# Why do we use anti-inflammatory drugs?

Tags: anti-inflammatory

If inflammation is a natural response of the body against injury or infection, why do we take anti-inflammatory drugs such as ibuprofen? Wouldn't that inhibit this defense mechanisms?

Comment: Immune response can be too much of a "good thing"; see allegies.